# Cannot click to focus on / edit floated form elements

Tags: html, css, grid, css-float, zurb-foundation

I'm using [Zurb Foundation's Grid](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/forms.html) to lay out a form. When I floated the the first few text and select inputs to lay them out in 2 columns, I lost the ability to click on them to edit them.  Note that I could edit them by tabbing through the inputs.

Check out the [example demonstrating the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/prembo/pEzYu/).

The textarea below the floated inputs could be clicked to focus and edited normally.

When I removed the `float: left;` from `form#Form_Form div.field.text, form#Form_Form div.field.dropdown` all the elements could be edited normally.

What's preventing the floated inputs from receiving focus when being clicked?

After some investigation, I discovered why - hope the following answer helps other stuck with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

All I had to do was to float the textarea as well.  See the [working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/prembo/j9umH/).

```
form#Form_Form div.field.textarea {
    ...
    float: left;
    // clear: both;  // clearing also worked.
}
```

The textarea's div which wasn't floated was *'covering'* the floated inputs, preventing the inputs from receiving focus when clicking with the mouse.  Hence [another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281271/why-a-fixed-element-covers-a-floated-element) is to alter the 'z-index' so that the textarea's div was below the floated inputs.